# how to push button to the bottom of screen in a layout file?

Tags: android, layout

I have the following layout.xml in my android app. I want to move the button to the bottom of the screen. Just right on top of my ads. but it will stay just right under the listview. how can I achieve this? I have tried layout_gravity="bottom|right" also tried layout_alignParentBottom="true" none of which places the button where I want. any help appreciated

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_main"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--custome toolbar-->
    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <!--Wifi name and state-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_wifi_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wifi_icon_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_wifi_white_36dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wifi_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="SOHOWIFI" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Progess bar-->
    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_local"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:text="Local Network:"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <!-- output of list local ip and public ip-->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/local_network"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="scan"
        android:id="@+id/scan_button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="12dp" />


    <!-- banner ads for AdsMob-->
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/app_banner_ad">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your parent view is a `LinearLayout` which may not be appropriate for what you want.  You can't use `layout_alignParentBottom` as a child of `LinearLayout`.  Consider using a `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Your button's parent layout is `LinearLayout`

`layout_gravity="bottom|right"` will work for `FrameLayout`

`layout_alignParentBottom="true"` will work for `RelativeLayout`

But you must change the parent layout with the appropriate layout.

Comment: I put my button inside a framelayout and still doesn't work. I'm using RelativeLayout not working. is at the end of my listview. I have ads at the end of the activity. and I want to place it on top the ad to the right.. I was able to do that with my ads by placing them inside a framelayout and push to bottom..